# Connect to wifi network after install driver manually linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

how to connect to WiFi network after manual driver install

I have successfully  installed the driver as so

```
sudo cp -R . /usr/src/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
```

Now how do i connect to WiFi, do i need to `modprobe` anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three install items you need to check to get this working:

1. Make sure the device driver is available and installed.
2. Edit the interface file.
3. Configure wpa_supplicant. This file controls "association".

These examples are taken from a Raspberry Pi install, a debian linux.

If you have the correct driver available you can simply reboot and the system should find it and install it for you. You need this to work properly for subsequent reboots of your system.

The interface file "/etc/network/interfaces" needs the following entry:

```
auto wlan0

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Finally, you need to edit "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf" to identify the wireless networks you wish to use:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="my-wireless-network"
    psk="secret-password-here"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Once you have those in place try:

```
ifup wlan0
```

and you might be on air.

All of these steps have a lot of different options and might vary depending on which linux distribution you are using and the particulars of your wireless hardware, so the example given above may have to be tweaked for your installation.